# nHibernate Join syntax error

Tags: nhibernate, syntax, join

I am doing my first nHibernate Join.  In my function below, I want to return a list of records for the specified query.  Normally my List type is the class representing the database table.  In this case, since I am doing a join, I created a custom class that only contains the fields for the columns I am retrieving from the database.  However, when I create the Query, I get "ERROR: 42601: syntax error at end of input" which seems to be related to the use of ReportColumns.  Can someone tell me if what I am doing is possible, and if not how this can be done?

```
public IList<ReportColumns> FetchRecords(NHibernateDBConnection db, string MyName)
{
    return db.Session
        .CreateQuery("SELECT s.RunNumber, s.TestStarted, s.StationName, t.Name FROM MyTable1 s, MyTable2 t WHERE (s.RunNumber = t.RunNumber AND t.Name = :MyName")
        .SetParameter("MyName", MyName)
        .List<ReportColumns>();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the right parenthesis.

Comment: Good eye. I fixed this, but the query is still not accepted.  I am getting an exception with:

{"The value \"System.Object[]\" is not of type \"MyApp.MyTable+ReportColumns\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value"}

Any other ideas as well?

Comment: I had overlooked that. You are selecting a list of arbitrary fiels, NHibernate will return that as a List<object[]>. If you need a list of ReportColumn, you need to use a transformer or a Linq-to-objects projection.